# Cannot assign value type 'Data?' to type 'UIImage?'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uikit

Im trying to pass data from viewcontroller to be displayed in secondviewcontroller. Im a beginner and need help as i have been able pass string and show display the data.

P.S im currently an intern (Wfh) with no seniors that has coding experience and in need of help. Im learning on the job and im stuck here for days.

[SecondViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7bxI.png)

[Core data entity and attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxmQR.png)

[ViewController Segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDRat.png)

Comment: `UIImage(data: someData)`, that how you init a `UIImage` from `Data`.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Im sorry i couldn't share all the relevant code as text using proper formatting as i am currently remote sharing my manager's macbook and I am not allowed to open chrome or any other app on his mac. Strictly only xcode and I resorted to taking screenshot via my windows PC to share on this question. Hope you can understand. Thank you

Comment: @AbednegoDavid You couldn't do copy/paste? That's what was asking Dávid Pásztor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
if let data = selectedNode?.image {
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```